# using Beamer alert in pgfplots figures

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, pgf-pie

I would like to add `\alert` to certain parts of graphs in a Beamer presentation while I'm talking about them, namely highlighting pgfplots values.

I managed to higlight labels by using `\alert<2>{...}`, but I'm not sure how to go about highlighting the values.

Here is a MWE including a sample graph:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator={\,},
}
\def\ScanPercentage#1\afternumber{\SI{#1}{\percent}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Bar Chart}
    \begin{figure}
      \scriptsize
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          symbolic x coords={18--24, 25--34, 35--44, 45--54},
          xtick=data,
          ylabel={Group 1},
          xlabel={Group 2},
          ymin=0, ymax=60,
          nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta{ }\%},
          yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}{ }\%},]
          \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
            (18--24, 18.9)
            (25--34, 48.4)
            (35--44, 18.0)
            (45--54, 14.7)
          };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do that. (I am also loading `overlay-beamer-styles` here even though at this point it is not yet needed, so at this point this is only to draw your attention to this nice library.)

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\newcounter{nnc}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Bar Chart}
    \begin{figure}
      \scriptsize
      \centering\setcounter{nnc}{0}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
          symbolic x coords={18--24, 25--34, 35--44, 45--54},
          xtick=data,
          ylabel={Group 1},
          xlabel={Group 2},
          ymin=0, ymax=60,
          nodes near coords={\stepcounter{nnc}%
          \alert<\number\value{nnc}>{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta{ }\%}},
          yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}{ }\%},]
          \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
            (18--24, 18.9)
            (25--34, 48.4)
            (35--44, 18.0)
            (45--54, 14.7)
          };
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I imagined. Splitting the question in two sounds like a good idea, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @TomášSláma You could just drop the first part of your question in this post and use it as a second question. Asking questions is free (and even appreciated if they are new, like yours, I think, are.)

Comment: I will do that then. Thanks so much for your help!